# Enterprise Library 5 Hybrid Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

We are using Enterprise Library 5.0 and would like to use the Logging application block to write log/trace messages to the Database. Doing all of the configuration in the `web.config` file works like a champ.

However, when the application starts up we need to be able to specify the database connection string that the logger uses dynamically. We thought that we might be able to take a hybrid approach by using the Ent Lib 5.0 Fluent API to register the connection string programmatically and then merge that with the configuration values from the `web.config`. This would allow us to be able to reconfigure how/where the trace messages are written without having to change the code.

This is what we have tried:

```cs
var dynamicConnectionString = "..."  // value determined elsewhere

var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();
builder.ConfigureData()
    .ForDatabaseNamed( "TestDB" ).ThatIs.ASqlDatabase()
    .WithConnectionString( dynamicConnectionString );

var configSource = new SystemConfigurationSource();
// the line below throws an ArgumentException with the message
// 'Cannot add a ConfigurationSection with the same name that already exists'
builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace( configSource );
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.CreateDefaultContainer( configSource );
```

In the `web.config` file for our test project we only define the `loggingConfiguration` section as follows:

```xml
<loggingConfiguration ...>
    <listeners>
        <add databaseInstanceName="TestDB" ... />
    </listeners>
    <formatters>...</formatters>
    <categorySources>...</categorySources>
    <specialSources>...</specialSources>
</loggingConfiguration>
```

If I inspect the builder object in the debugger, it only has 1 section defined: a `connectionStrings` section that contains a single `connectionString` entry with the values I specified through code. The `web.config` file **doesn't** contain a `connectionStrings` section at all.

Ironically, if I use the Immediate/Watch Window and inspect `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`, it reports that there is 1 connection already defined... the default (`"data source=.\SQLExpress;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttacheDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"`) connection.

If I add `<connectionStrings><clear /></connectionStrings>` to clear the inherited values, when I debug again I still get the same exception as before **and** VS notifies me that the `web.config` file has been updated (if I reload the file, the `<connectionStrings>` section has been removed).

What am I missing here! This can't be that hard!

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about this over the weekend and doing a little more digging, I found a [Blog Post](https://randylevy.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/enterprise-library-programmatic-configuration/) that helped me resolve my issues. This is how it is working for me:

```cs
var builder = new ConfigurationSourceBuilder();
// Configure the dataSource (connection string)
builder.ConfigureData()
    .ForDatabaseNamed( "TestDB" )
        .ThatIs.ASqlDatabase()
        // this would be determined at runtime; not statically defined
        .WithConnectionString( @"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=Logging;Integrated Security=True" )
    .AsDefault();

// create a new config source
var configSource = new DictionaryConfigurationSource();
builder.UpdateConfigurationWithReplace( configSource );

IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();

// load the default configuration information from the config file
// i.e. ConfigurationSourceFactory.Create()
// and add it to the container
container.AddNewExtension<EnterpriseLibraryCoreExtension>();

// create a configurator to use to configure our fluent configuration
var configurator = new UnityContainerConfigurator( container );
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.ConfigureContainer( configurator, configSource );

// Use the configured container with file and fluent config as the Enterprise Library service locator
EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current = new UnityServiceLocator( container );

// Write a log entry using the Logger facade
LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry
{
    EventId = 180,
    Priority = 1,
    Message = "Message",
    Categories = { "AccessAudit" }
};

Logger.Write( logEntry );
```

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: Glad you found the blog useful.